# How to get every first element from the multidimensional array in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional (2D) `@array`.

I wrote following code to get the first element from the every nested array:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @array = (
    [ '/dev/vg00/lvol6', 114224,  46304,   67920,   '41%', '/home' ],
    [ '/dev/vg00/lvol7', 8340704, 4336752, 4003952, '52%', '/opt' ],
    [ '/dev/vg00/lvol4', 520952,  35080,   485872,  '7%',  '/tmp' ],
);

my @new_array;

foreach (@array) {
    push @new_array, @$_[0];
}
```

Is there a better or faster way (for example, with using the `map` function) to produce a new array (every first element/value from the nested array) with following values:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '/dev/vg00/lvol6',
          '/dev/vg00/lvol7',
          '/dev/vg00/lvol4'
        ];
```

PS. I'm sorry for trivial question, but today (in the monday morning) I've a big blank out in my head today.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [map, and click here for the perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html)

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @array = (
             ['/dev/vg00/lvol6', 114224, 46304, 67920, '41%', '/home'],
             ['/dev/vg00/lvol7', 8340704, 4336752, 4003952, '52%', '/opt'],
             ['/dev/vg00/lvol4', 520952, 35080, 485872, '7%', '/tmp']
            );

my @new_array = map { $_->[0] } @array; 

print Dumper(\@new_array);
```

This prints out:

```
$VAR1 = [
      '/dev/vg00/lvol6',
      '/dev/vg00/lvol7',
      '/dev/vg00/lvol4'
    ];
```

Comment: Excellent. The *proper* way.

Comment: What would be improper, a foreach loop?

Answer (score 3):

```
my @new_array = map $_->[0], @array;
```

Although `map` may not be faster option,

```
my @array = (
      ['/dev/vg00/lvol6', 114224, 46304, 67920, '41%', '/home'],
      ['/dev/vg00/lvol7', 8340704, 4336752, 4003952, '52%', '/opt'],
      ['/dev/vg00/lvol4', 520952, 35080, 485872, '7%', '/tmp']
);
sub umap {
  my @new_array = map $_->[0], @array;
  return;
}
sub ufor {
  my @new_array;
  foreach (@array) {
      push @new_array, $_->[0];
  }
  return;
}

use Benchmark qw( cmpthese ) ;
cmpthese( -5, {
    umap => \&umap,
    ufor => \&ufor,
});
```

result

```
         Rate umap ufor
umap 691765/s   -- -14%
ufor 804475/s  16%   --
```

Comment: premature optimization (and a bad benchmark to boot)

Comment: umap returns @new_array; ufor doesn't.

Comment: (though fixing that doesn't change the results by much)